# Bash " * " equivalent in windows?

Tags: windows, bash

I'm using windows for a project instead of linux that involves the use of cmd.  I want to know the "command" for cmd to include all files in an action (e.g bash would be "(things to do the the files) *", except in windows CMD format.

Comment: im converting file types, so i need to be able to select all the files of a specific file type (as if im moving files i would do something like "mv *.png -t /destination/folder")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think to test " * " in cmd.